# Convert jQuery to JavaScript - mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert this jQuery Code into Vanilla JavaScript code. I'm having trouble with some of the methods. I think I have some of them, but some of them not.

Jquery:

```
jQuery('.image').click(function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('normal-zoom zoom-in');
});

jQuery('.image').on('mousemove', function(event) {

  var bbox = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var mouseX = event.clientX - bbox.left;
  var mouseY = event.clientY - bbox.top;
  var xPercent = (mouseX / bbox.width) * 100;
  var yPercent = (mouseY / bbox.height) * 100;

  jQuery(this).css('transform-origin', (xPercent+'% ' + yPercent+ '%') );

});

jQuery('.image').on('mouseenter', function() {
  jQuery(this).addClass('zoom-in');
  jQuery(this).removeClass('normal-zoom');
});

jQuery('.image').on('mouseleave', function() {
  jQuery(this).addClass('normal-zoom');
  jQuery(this).removeClass('zoom-in');
});
```

I tried.

Javascript:

```
document.querySelector('.image').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector(this).classList.toggle('normal-zoom zoom-in');
};

document.querySelector('.image').addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {

  var bbox = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var mouseX = event.clientX - bbox.left;
  var mouseY = event.clientY - bbox.top;
  var xPercent = (mouseX / bbox.width) * 100;
  var yPercent = (mouseY / bbox.height) * 100;

  document.querySelector(this).css('transform-origin', (xPercent+'% ' + yPercent+ '%') );

});

document.querySelector('.image').addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  document.querySelector(this).classList.add('zoom-in');
  document.querySelector(this).classList.remove('normal-zoom');
});

document.querySelector('.image').addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  document.querySelector(this).classList.add('normal-zoom');
  document.querySelector(this).classList.remove('zoom-in');
});
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added two comments to the code to show two lines I fixed and why they needed fixing.

Additionally, I replaced every instance of `document.querySelector(this)` with `document.querySelector('.image')`, because the callbacks inside `.onclick` and `.addEventListener` do not bind `this` to the selected element the same way JQuery does, so you need to re-select the element each time. In your code, `this` is referencing the callback function, which is not what you want.

```
document.querySelector('.image').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.image').classList.toggle('zoom-in');// I split this line into two lines, because `.toggle()` can only accept one classname at a time.
  document.querySelector('.image').classList.toggle('normal-zoom');
};

document.querySelector('.image').addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  var bbox = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var mouseX = event.clientX - bbox.left;
  var mouseY = event.clientY - bbox.top;
  var xPercent = (mouseX / bbox.width) * 100;
  var yPercent = (mouseY / bbox.height) * 100;

  document.querySelector('.image').style.transformOrigin = xPercent+'% ' + yPercent+'%';// There is no such `.css()` method on DOM nodes. Instead, set an element's css by using the `style` property.
});

document.querySelector('.image').addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  document.querySelector('.image').classList.add('zoom-in');
  document.querySelector('.image').classList.remove('normal-zoom');
});

document.querySelector('.image').addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  document.querySelector('.image').classList.add('normal-zoom');
  document.querySelector('.image').classList.remove('zoom-in');
});
```

I would recommend using this code instead though, as it's cleaner, easier to read, implements DRY practices, and works to prevent bugs related to changes in the DOM.

```
const imageElement = document.querySelector('.image');

imageElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
  imageElement.classList.toggle('zoom-in');
  imageElement.classList.toggle('normal-zoom');
};

imageElement.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  const bbox = imageElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  const mouseX = event.clientX - bbox.left;
  const mouseY = event.clientY - bbox.top;
  const xPercent = (mouseX / bbox.width) * 100;
  const yPercent = (mouseY / bbox.height) * 100;

  imageElement.style.transformOrigin = xPercent+'% ' + yPercent+'%';
});

imageElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  imageElement.classList.add('zoom-in');
  imageElement.classList.remove('normal-zoom');
});

imageElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  imageElement.classList.add('normal-zoom');
  imageElement.classList.remove('zoom-in');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I understand better now.